# webpack code splitting,react not update

Tags: reactjs, webpack

use webpack code splitting,react view not updata when i change state.

code:

```
//main.js
export default class extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            textview: undefined,
            text: 'text'
        }
    }
    _loadText() {
        if (!this.state.textview)
            require.ensure([], require => {
                const Text = require('./text').default;
                this.setState({
                    textview: <Text text={this.state.text} />
                })
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Main</div>
                <button onClick={() => this._loadText()}>load</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ text: 'change' })}>change</button>
                {this.state.textview}
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

//test.js
export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.text}</div>

        )
    }
}
```

when i click load button ,the Text component can load and visible.

but when i click change button ,the Text can not update  text value.

Is there anyone who can help me? thanks

Comment: Checkout this article - https://medium.com/prod-io/code-splitting-in-react-using-webpack-1aa1014da216

Answer (score 0):

in _loadText()

```
this.setState({
textview: Text
})
```

render()

```
<div>
<div>Main</div>
<button onClick={() => this._loadText()}>load</button>
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ text: 'change' })}>change</button>
{this.state.textview ? React.createElement(this.state.textview, { text: this.state.text }) : null}
```

It worked